# How to use Method of Eigenfunction Expansion to solve a non-homogeneous PDE with 3 independent variables?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a single PDE in the following form:

$$
\frac{\partial Z}{\partial t} + k\frac{\partial Z}{\partial x} - D\frac{\partial^{2} Z}{\partial y^{2}} = f(x,y,t)
$$

$k$ and $D$ are constants.

This is a non-homogeneous PDE, and I'm trying to find an analytical solution. I'm attempting to solve using the method of Eigenfunction Expansion, however, every resource I could find about this method involved a PDE with just 2 independent variables, and I'm not sure how to extend that method to a PDE with 3 independent variables.

In 2 variables, one would assume the solution has the form:
$$
Z(y,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}(t)\phi_{n}(y)
$$
With $\phi_{n}(y)$ being an Eigenfunction, which can be obtained from separation of variables, and $a_{n}(t)$ determined from the initial condition and forcing term. If it's possible to extend that general solution to 3 independent variables, would the solution look something like this?
$$
Z(x,y,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}(x,t)\phi_{n}(y)
$$
Or this?
$$
Z(x,y,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}(t)b_{n}(x)\phi_{n}(y)
$$
Or would it look like something else entirely? I'm also wondering if this method is the best way of solving the problem, or if there is a better technique I should be using.

Comment: A separable solution will necessarily require $Z_{n}$ to have the form $a_{n}(t) b_{n}(x) \phi_{n}(y)$. And the best method to use depends on the boundary conditions.

Comment: Boundary Conditions are: $Z(x=0, y, t) = 0$, $\frac{\partial Z}{\partial y}|_{y=0} = 0$, and $\frac{\partial Z}{\partial y}|_{y=W_{I}} = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

#### Reduction to decoupled system:

Notice that $Y_n(y) = \cos \frac{n\pi y}{W_I}$ satisfies the $y$-boundary conditions as well as $Y'' = -\mu_n^2 Y$, where $\mu_N= \frac{n\pi y}{W_I}$. We then expand both $Z$ and $f$ in a Fourier cosine series on $[0,W_I]$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
Z(x,y,t) &= a_0(x,t) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos \mu_n y, \\
f(x,y,t) &= b_0(x,t) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \cos \mu_n y,
\end{aligned}
$$
where
$$
\begin{aligned}
b_0(x,t) &= \frac{1}{W_I}\int_0^{W_I} f(x,y,t)~\mathrm{d}y \\
b_n(x,t) &= \frac{2}{W_I}\int_0^{W_I} f(x,y,t)\cos \mu_n y~\mathrm{d}y, \, n>0. 
\end{aligned}
$$

Substituting this into the PDE and equating like Fourier coefficients, we obtain an infinite uncoupled system of nonhomogeneous hyperbolic PDEs:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} a_0 + k \frac{\partial}{\partial x} a_0 &= b_0 \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} a_n + k \frac{\partial}{\partial x} a_n +D\mu_n^2 a_n&= b_n,\, n>0.
\end{aligned}
$$

It is here that I make two assumptions:

1. There is an initial condition $Z_0(x,y)$ defined on $(0,\infty)\times(0,W_I)$. We similarly expand it in its Fourier cosine series with coefficients $c_n(x)$. It must then be the case as that $a_n(x,0) = c_n(x)$ for all $n$.
2. $k\geq0$. If $k<0$, then the values of $a_n$ along the boundary $x=0$ are uniquelly determined by the values of $c_n$ and $b_n$ and it may be impossible to enforce $Z=0$ here. However, if $k$ is nonnegative that this boundary condition can be enforced for arbitrary initial conditions. We proceed under this assumption and handle the cases of $k=0$ and $k>0$ separately.

#### Case $1$: $k=0$

In this case, each of the hyperbolic PDEs reduces to a one-parameter family of ODEs parameterized by the location $x$ with solutions given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
a_0(x,t) &= c_0(x) + \int_0^tb_0(x,s)~\mathrm{d}s, \\
a_n(x,t) &= c_n(x) + \int_0^t e^{-D\mu_n^2(t-s)}b_n(x,s)~\mathrm{d}s,\, n>0.
\end{aligned}
$$

#### Case $2$: $k>0$

In this case, we have a hypberolic PDE governing the behavior of each Fourier coefficient. The characteristic lines are given by $x - kt = C$ and the solution behavior along these lines is given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d a_0}{ds} &= b_0, \\
\frac{d a_n}{ds} &= -D\mu^2a_n + b_n, 
\end{aligned}
$$
where $s$ parameterizes along the characteristic lines. The initial conditions are given by either the $x=0$ BC or the intial condition. Furthermore, since equation equation is hyperbolic, we must consider two subcases corresponding to $kt > x$ or $ kt< x$, as in these regions, the solution will be uniquely determined by either the $x=0$ boundary condition or the initial condition, respectively.

##### Case $2.1$: $kt > x$

This region contains all points lying above the characteristic $kt - x = 0$ in the $x$-$t$ plane and these characteristics emanate from the boundary $x=0$. We parameterize the characteristic lines as $x(s) = \tau$ and $t(s) = \frac{s}{k} + t_0$, which yields $t_0 = t - \frac{x}{k}$. Each ODE has the same initial condition for each $t_0$ equal to $0$ from the BC. Integrating the characteristic equations then yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
a_0(x,t) &= \int_0^x b_0\left(s,t-\frac{s}{k}\right) ~\mathrm{d}s \\
a_n(x,t) &= \int_0^x e^{-D\mu_n^2(x-s)} b_n\left(\xi,t-\frac{s}{k}\right) ~\mathrm{d}s,\, n>0.
\end{aligned}
$$

##### Case $2.2$: $kt < x$

Here we have a similar situation except that the characteristic lines now emanate from the line $t=0$ and the initial conditions of the ODEs are now given by $c_n(x_0)$. The characteristic lines are given by $t(s) = s$ and $x(s) = ks + x_0$, which yields $x - kt = x_0$. The characteristic equation for $a_n$ along this line now has initial condition $c_n(x_0) = c_n(x-kt)$. The solution to these ODEs is then
$$
\begin{aligned}
a_0(x,t) &= c_0(x - kt) + \int_0^t b_0\left(x-ks,s\right) ~\mathrm{d}s \\
a_n(x,t) &= c_n(x - kt) + \int_0^t e^{-D\mu_n^2(t-s)} b_n\left(x - ks,s\right) ~\mathrm{d}s,\, n>0.
\end{aligned}
$$

#### Final Solution

$$
Z(x,y,t) = a_0(x,t) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(x,t)\cos \mu_n y,
$$
where $\mu_n = \frac{n\pi}{W_I}$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
a_0(x,t) &= \begin{cases}
\int_0^x b_0\left(s,t-\frac{s}{k}\right) ~\mathrm{d}s, & x < kt \\
c_0(x - kt) + \int_0^t b_0\left(x-ks,s\right) ~\mathrm{d}s, & x > kt,
\end{cases} \\
\\
a_n(x,t) &= \begin{cases}
\int_0^x e^{-D\mu_n^2(x-s)} b_n\left(\xi,t-\frac{s}{k}\right) ~\mathrm{d}s, & x < kt \\
c_n(x - kt) + \int_0^t e^{-D\mu_n^2(t-s)} b_n\left(x - ks,s\right) ~\mathrm{d}s, & x > kt,\,n>0,
\end{cases} 
\end{aligned}
$$
and where
$$
\begin{aligned}
b_0(x,t) &= \frac{1}{W_I}\int_0^{W_I} f(x,y,t)~\mathrm{d}y \\
b_n(x,t) &= \frac{2}{W_I}\int_0^{W_I} f(x,y,t)\cos \mu_n y~\mathrm{d}y, \, n>0,
\\ \text{and}\\
c_0(x,t) &= \frac{1}{W_I}\int_0^{W_I} Z_0(x,y)~\mathrm{d}y \\
c_n(x,t) &= \frac{2}{W_I}\int_0^{W_I} Z_0(x,y)\cos \mu_n y~\mathrm{d}y, \, n>0.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this should help me immensely! I do have one question: For the Case where $k > 0$, what happens if $kt = x$?

Comment: The function is discontinuous in general unless $\lim_{x\to0} Z_0(x,y) = 0$, in which case the two conditions will give the same value along this line.